# How can I obtain all fields of multiform/data-form using OpenApi 3 and Multer in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, multer

What I want to accomplish it to upload a file with other text data of multiple other fields (example in the attached screenshot).

[image]

I am using Express and Multer, my problem is that my controller couldn't get the image file and the 2 text fields. I am only receiving the image (`req.files` not empty but `req.body` is empty).

here is my code sample:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.text());

const path = require('path');
const apiSpec = path.join(__dirname, './api.yaml');
const OpenApiValidator = require('express-openapi-validator');
app.use(OpenApiValidator.middleware({
  apiSpec: apiSpec,
  additionalProperties: false,
  validateRequests: true,
  validateResponses: false
}));

const multer = require('multer');
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post('/upload', upload.single('fileUpload'), (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.files);
        console.log(req.body);

        // UPLOAD LOGIC . . .

        res.status(201).send();
    } catch (err) {
        next(err)
    }
});
```

My output is as follow:

```
(1) [{...}]     //THIS IS req.files
{}              //THIS IS req.body
```

the `req.files` hold only one item which is the image upload, but no trace of `fileId` and `author`.

Any idea of what am I doing wrong?

NOTE: Please also note that if I use `upload.fields([{ name: fieldName, maxCount: 1}, ...])` or `upload.any()` I get `[]` for `req.files`.

---

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks to `taipei`'s answer that did help me redirect my searches. I didn't mention that I am also using OpenApiValidator (`express-openapi-validator`) and by disabling it, everything did work fine, so I believe these must be something off in my `api.yml` configuration

```
  /upload:
    post:
      summary: Upload file with text data
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                fileId:
                  type: string
                fileUpload:
                  type: string
                  format: binary
                author:
                  type: string
      responses:
        '201':
          description: Uploaded file with text data
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  message: 
                    type: string
```

Thank you all for your assistance, if I missed any details please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the form-data field name for the file.
For your example, you need to use `fileUpload` as the param value in `upload.single()`

And I think you can't use the root ( / ) as the path, you need to use a specific path for the request.

```js
...
app.post('/upload', upload.single('fileUpload'), (req, res) => {
...
```

in your logic, since you only use a single file, you need to use `req.file` instead of `req.files`

you can see the full code here

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.text());

const multer  = require('multer');
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post('/upload', upload.single('fileUpload'), (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.file);
        console.log(req.body);

        // UPLOAD LOGIC . . .

        res.status(201).send();
    } catch (err) {
        next(err)
    }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

references:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, this didn't work: By adding the file name in `single()`, adding a path: I could parse the body (it's not empty anymore) but `req.files` & `req.file` are **undefined**

Comment: Could you please update your code with current changes, and actually if you try to run my code it works well on my end.

Comment: I did test your code but it didn't work at first, I needed to rechoose the file in Postman in order to make it work so you were right. This pushed me to dig deeper to try to find the issue I am having on my app (code given is just a sample) and I came out to the conclusion that OpenAPI (what I am currently using in my real app) is creating the weird behaviour described in my question. I am updating my question